# RewriteCond for a folder only on a specific domain extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a site that can be accessed via 3 domains (domain.com, domain.ch, domain.fr). The three use exactly the same files and folder, though.

Regarding the `.fr` domain (and **only** this domain), I need the following:

1. redirect `domain.fr` (root) to `domain.com/fr/france`.

This has been achieved with the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.fr$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/fr\/france" [R=301,L]
```

It works. (There's also a functioning rule to force www. in front of every URL.)

What I *can't* get to work is:

2. redirect `domain.fr/fr` also to `domain.com/fr/france`.
3. and finally, redirect any URL `domain.fr/fr/*` to `domain.com/fr/*`
   (keeping whatever * stands for).

The trick (to me) is that the same .htaccess file will also be present on domain.com and domain.ch, but those rules must not activate for those domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put these rules in your htaccess

```
# Redirect [www.]domain.fr and [www.]domain.fr/fr to www.domain.com/fr/france
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(|fr)$ http://www.domain.com/fr/france [R=301,L]

# Redirect domain.fr/fr/* to domain.com/fr/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.fr$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/france
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/fr/france/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I'm afraid. Not to worry, the other answer did the trick. Thanks anyway.